# figcaption issue in responsive aviatar

Tags: html, css

I'm tried to used responsive aviatar for my main page in [website](http://osakaairport.com/), everything works well except the figcaption that giving problems both in desktop view and media query.

Any suggestion or workaround I should modify.

```css
.breakpoint { /* One column for smartphones */
  max-width: 33%;
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 4px;
}

.breakpoint figcaption {
  text-align: center;
  padding-top: 5px;
  font-style: italic;
  font-size: 8px;
  text-indent: 0;  
}
```

```html
<section id="responsive-images-breakpoints">
  <a href="public_transport/index.htm">
    <img class="breakpoint avatar" src="images/airport-kix/airport-bus.jpg" alt="Public Transport">
    <figcaption>Public Transport</figcaption>
  </a>
```

Answer (score 0):

The figcaption element should be embedded inside the figure element.

Example:

```
<figure>
    <img src="" alt="">
    <figcaption></figcaption>
</figure>
```

Comment: not working, pls see the website (osakaairport.com) after added in the suggested coding.